# Radio buttons in ember 2.0

Tags: javascript, ember.js

So its been a month with ember right now, im really happy with it but getting information is kind of hard due to the amount of versions there is and how they change stuff between versions.

Regarding build in input elements i have found the following

```
for text type fields
{{input class='input' type='email' value=email}} 

{{textarea value=pictureDescription class='textarea' id='coolTextArea' value=content}}

{{input type="checkbox"  checked=model.allowComments}}

{{input type="file"  name="image"  value=image class='hidden_file'  }}

even cool selects

{{view "select"
                            content=languagePreferences
                            optionValuePath="content.code"
                            optionLabelPath="content.label"
                            class="my-dropdown" value=model.submisionType}}
```

which was kind of confusing since i read in older versions selects were kind of complicated.

Whats the deal with radio buttons?  Are there native radio buttons ? or should i use something like :

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-radio-buttons

i dont want to use strange dependencies (as i used to with x-select) when there are native available

Thanks in advance

UPDATE
So after runspired recomendation i tried this

```
  <form action='' onchange={{action 'updateValue' value='target.value' }}>
                               <p><input type="radio" name="follow-option"  value='op1' >Option1</p>
                               <p><input type="radio" name="follow-option" checked  value='op2' > Option 2 </p>
</form>
```

on my component/controller i have

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    myValue:null,

    actions:{
        updateValue(value){

            console.log('Got value ',value);

        }
    }


});
```

I get the following message on chromes console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined
```

and nothing gets shown. What am I missing?

Comment: You don't actually need to use any of these things with ember 1.13+, I'll find you the gist

Comment: http://jsbin.com/febafarova/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Wow that was really a game changer. Thank u very much

Comment: Im sorry ive been trying with your example but i still dont get it. it doesnt really work for me im getting a ' Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined'  Ill update my question to show some code